# Creating bar plot of multiple years in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a dataset with data for multiple years. I have taken each year and obtained the mean, which is shown below.

```
## structure(list(X = 1:10, Sector = c("B01", "B02", "B03", "B04", 
 "B05", "B06", "B07", "B08", "B09", "B10"), Octant = c("NW", "N", 
 "NE", "NW", "NW", "N", "N", "NE", "NE", "W"), Distance_m = c(1600L, 
 1600L, 1600L, 3200L, 3200L, 3200L, 3200L, 3200L, 3200L, 4800L
 ), Yr1951 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Yr1952 = c(4.16722556361885, 
 8.07009038922937, 19.9170847727104, 3.14049476463692, 3.14049476463692, 
 6.08176260934446, 6.08176260934446, 15.0098667568185, 15.0098667568185, 
 4.65320683317187), Yr1953 = c(15.7901552659006, 30.578613590843, 
 75.4684036666576, 11.8997398120925, 11.8997398120925, 23.0445831227103, 
 23.0445831227103, 56.8743215341634, 56.8743215341634, 17.6316009916985
 ), Yr1954 = c(23.2458594045635, 45.0170464032273, 111.102637787894, 
 17.5184900949112, 17.5184900949112, 33.9256410267316, 33.9256410267316, 
 83.7289095546898, 83.7289095546898, 25.9567883170532), Yr1955 = c(23.2458594045635, 
 45.0170464032273, 111.102637787894, 17.5184900949112, 17.5184900949112, 
 33.9256410267316, 33.9256410267316, 83.7289095546898, 83.7289095546898, 
 25.9567883170532), Yr1956 = c(23.2458594045635, 45.0170464032273, 
 111.102637787894, 17.5184900949112, 17.5184900949112, 33.9256410267316, 
 33.9256410267316, 83.7289095546898, 83.7289095546898, 25.9567883170532
 ), Yr1957 = c(23.2458594045635, 45.0170464032273, 111.102637787894, 
 17.5184900949112, 17.5184900949112, 33.9256410267316, 33.9256410267316, 
 83.7289095546898, 83.7289095546898, 25.9567883170532), Yr1958 = c(24.6439039639345, 
 47.724446276369, 117.78453479105, 18.5720811598549, 18.5720811598549, 
 35.9659853751658, 35.9659853751658, 88.7645051172278, 88.7645051172278, 
 27.517872639807), Yr1959 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 
 137.830225800518, 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 
 42.0870184204684, 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683
 ), Yr1960 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 137.830225800518, 
 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 42.0870184204684, 
 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683), Yr1961 = c(28.8380376420477, 
 55.8466458957943, 137.830225800518, 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 
 42.0870184204684, 42.0870184204684, 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 
 32.2011256080683), Yr1962 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 
 137.830225800518, 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 
 42.0870184204684, 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683
 ), Yr1963 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 137.830225800518, 
 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 42.0870184204684, 
 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683), Yr1964 = c(28.8380376420477, 
 55.8466458957943, 137.830225800518, 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 
 42.0870184204684, 42.0870184204684, 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 
 32.2011256080683), Yr1965 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 
 137.830225800518, 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 
 42.0870184204684, 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683
 ), Yr1966 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 137.830225800518, 
 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 42.0870184204684, 
 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683), Yr1967 = c(28.8380376420477, 
 55.8466458957943, 137.830225800518, 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 
 42.0870184204684, 42.0870184204684, 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 
 32.2011256080683), Yr1968 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 
137.830225800518, 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 
 42.0870184204684, 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683
 ), Yr1969 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 137.830225800518, 
 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 42.0870184204684, 
 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683), Yr1970 = c(28.8380376420477, 
 55.8466458957943, 137.830225800518, 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 
 42.0870184204684, 42.0870184204684, 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 
 32.2011256080683), Yr1971 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 
 137.830225800518, 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 
 42.0870184204684, 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683
 ), Yr1972 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 137.830225800518, 
 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 42.0870184204684, 
 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683), Yr1973 = c(28.8380376420477, 
 55.8466458957943, 137.830225800518, 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 
 42.0870184204684, 42.0870184204684, 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 
 32.2011256080683), Yr1974 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 
 137.830225800518, 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 
 42.0870184204684, 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683
 ), Yr1975 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 137.830225800518, 
 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 42.0870184204684, 
 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683), Yr1976 = c(28.8380376420477, 
 55.8466458957943, 137.830225800518, 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 
 42.0870184204684, 42.0870184204684, 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 
 32.2011256080683), Yr1977 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 
 137.830225800518, 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 
 42.0870184204684, 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683
 ), Yr1978 = c(28.8380376420477, 55.8466458957943, 137.830225800518, 
 21.7328543546861, 21.7328543546861, 42.0870184204684, 42.0870184204684, 
 103.871291804842, 103.871291804842, 32.2011256080683), Yr1979 = c(16.6426332897682, 
 32.2294900798683, 79.5427876444474, 12.5421823029183, 12.5421823029183, 
 24.2887127940458, 24.2887127940458, 59.9448492404336, 59.9448492404336, 
 18.5834948849451), Yr1980 = c(4.44722893748883, 8.61233426394242, 
 21.2553494883767, 3.35151025115061, 3.35151025115061, 6.49040716762317, 
 6.49040716762317, 16.0184066760251, 16.0184066760251, 4.96586416182185
 ), Yr1981 = c(4.44722893748883, 8.61233426394242, 21.2553494883767, 
 3.35151025115061, 3.35151025115061, 6.49040716762317, 6.49040716762317, 
 16.0184066760251, 16.0184066760251, 4.96586416182185), Yr1982 = c(4.44722893748883, 
 8.61233426394242, 21.2553494883767, 3.35151025115061, 3.35151025115061, 
 6.49040716762317, 6.49040716762317, 16.0184066760251, 16.0184066760251, 
 4.96586416182185), Yr1983 = c(4.44722893748883, 8.61233426394242, 
 21.2553494883767, 3.35151025115061, 3.35151025115061, 6.49040716762317, 
 6.49040716762317, 16.0184066760251, 16.0184066760251, 4.96586416182185
 ), Yr1984 = c(4.44722893748883, 8.61233426394242, 21.2553494883767, 
 3.35151025115061, 3.35151025115061, 6.49040716762317, 6.49040716762317, 
 16.0184066760251, 16.0184066760251, 4.96586416182185), Yr1985 = c(4.44722893748883, 
 8.61233426394242, 21.2553494883767, 3.35151025115061, 3.35151025115061, 
 6.49040716762317, 6.49040716762317, 16.0184066760251, 16.0184066760251, 
 4.96586416182185), Yr1986 = c(4.44722893748883, 8.61233426394242, 
 21.2553494883767, 3.35151025115061, 3.35151025115061, 6.49040716762317, 
 6.49040716762317, 16.0184066760251, 16.0184066760251, 4.96586416182185
 ), Yr1987 = c(4.44722893748883, 8.61233426394242, 21.2553494883767, 
 3.35151025115061, 3.35151025115061, 6.49040716762317, 6.49040716762317, 
 16.0184066760251, 16.0184066760251, 4.96586416182185), Yr1988 = c(1.1104088237638, 
 2.15037545723583, 5.30715372557456, 0.836823695861693, 0.836823695861693, 
 1.62056091333541, 1.62056091333541, 3.99956475497726, 3.99956475497726, 
 1.23990454739508)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
 ))
```

I need to create a bar plot containing individual bars for each year. How would I do this? The y axis can be named exposure, and the x would be year. I have not had experience beyond very simple barplots. I was also wondering how I could go about combining all of these years together and getting the overall mean and median.

Comment: It looks like the mean for each year is stored as a separate variable in your workspace. That is not a very good way to manage data and it makes creating plots of it very difficult. Can you share a sample of the original data on which this is based?

Comment: @jdobres I have edited to add the original code. I wasn't sure how to get the means of each year to create the bar plot, so that's why I originally had them separated out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For operations such as this, the **tidyverse** set of packages comes in very handy. **tidyverse** also includes **ggplot**, which is a great library for creating visualizations. There are a lot of great resources for learning more about the **tidyverse**, such as [this one](https://bookdown.org/yih_huynh/Guide-to-R-Book/tidyverse.html).

Here, I've named your data `df`. First, let's pivot the data into "long" format, in which each row contains one data value of interest, and then calculate the mean per year:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_means <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Yr'), names_to = 'year') %>% 
  mutate(year_numeric = as.numeric(gsub('Yr', '', year))) %>% 
  group_by(year_numeric) %>% 
  summarize(value = mean(value, na.rm = T))

   year_numeric value
          <dbl> <dbl>
 1         1951  0   
 2         1952  8.53
 3         1953 32.3 
 4         1954 47.6 
 5         1955 47.6 
 6         1956 47.6 
 7         1957 47.6 
 8         1958 50.4 
 9         1959 59.0 
10         1960 59.0 
# … with 28 more rows
```

We can do a similar operation without the `group_by` command to get the grand mean and median:

```
df_overall <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with('Yr'), names_to = 'year') %>% 
  summarize(
    grand_mean = mean(value, na.rm = T),
    grand_median = median(value, na.rm = T)
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = 'measure')

  measure      value
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 grand_mean    41.3
2 grand_median  28.8
```

And finally, we can create a plot with **ggplot**. Note how little plotting code is required to create something relatively complex:

```
plot_means <- df_means %>% 
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = year_numeric, y = value)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_hline(data = df_overall, aes(color = measure, yintercept = value)) +
  labs(x = 'Year', y = 'Exposure')
print(plot_means)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works well, except I have NAs in my full dataset, so the actual barplot cannot be formed. Where in the code could I insert na.rm=TRUE to get the desired result?

Comment: Inside the `mean` and `median` function calls (see edit). If my answer works for you, please mark it as correct and, optionally, upvote it.